# Django rest Docker with MySQL

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize my existing Django Rest project. I am using MySQL database instead of default SqlLite.

My Dockerfile looks like following:

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: docker
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: docker
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: 
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

I did not run `docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate`

`docker-compose build` is successful

However `docker-compose up` fails eventually saying `Can't connect to local MySQL server`. I am guessing that I need to install MySQl in my container as well, but do not know how. What am I missing in my Dockerfile or docker-compose?

**UPDATE:** My settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', #django.db.backends.mysql 
        'NAME': 'libraries', #local: libraries #server: 
        'USER': 'root', #root #root
        'PASSWORD': 'root', #local: root #server: 
        'HOST': 'localhost', #local: localhost  #server:
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: The mysql is already installed on the corresponding container. I guess the problem lies on how you connect to MySQL in your Python code. Can you post that Python part here as well as the detailed error log?

Comment: Hi! I updated my question with settings.py and another try for docker-compose with some settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `HOST` in the database settings from `localhost` to `db`. There's no MySQL in the `web` container so the Python code couldn't connect to the db.

Comment: Okay thanks! One quick question: I already have tables in my local database. Do I need to run `docker-compose web run python manage.py migrate` before build or up?

Comment: It still gave me :  `"Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)"`

Comment: @Nitish If you sure that the db is synced without your latest schema, you can skip it. However, there's no harm if you run `migrate` every time.

Comment: @Nitish didn't you set the db user to `docker`, not `root` ?

Comment: I am bit confused here. Must I change user to docker in settings.py as well?

Comment: @Nitish yes your settings in `settings.py` must match with the settings in your MySQL docker container, including database name, database user, and database password.

Comment: Is it not other way round? Like whatever is there in the settings.py, your docker-compose should contain the same?

Comment: It worked. Actually I had to run up command twice! Do not know why.